# SignalR Concurrent Request is more that 50 thousand

Tags: asp.net, signalr

We are using SignalR Technology for our web application, With IIS 7.5 and Windows 2008 R2 Server. Which has huge hits, that Concurrent request are more than 50 thousand. So when it reaches 5 thousand, afterwards it not responding for any request. So what is solution, Except Server up-gradation.

Calling Method is long-polling and Cross Domain Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [performance section](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance) of the documentation. You're hitting the default limit of 5000 concurrent connections. You can increase that value, but ultimately you'll have to look at a [scale-out](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-in-signalr) solution. (50,000 connections is a tall order for any server)